# Scatter plot with two categorical variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, categorical-data

I'm trying to make a scatter plot with the data provided below. I would have on the x-axis the values of two columns namely "Locus_ID" and "Start" which corresponds to the positions of each locus number. On the y-axis, I would represent the values of "sp_score". I have not figured out a way to combine the values of "Locus_ID" with "Start" to represent the graph I desire. For instance, I could only use just one variable on the x-axis, either "Locus_ID" or "Start", but not both. Is it possible to combine these two categorical variables as a factor?

```
> dput(head(file))
structure(list(Locus_ID = c("locus3", "locus3", "locus3", "locus3", 
"locus7", "locus7"), Start = c(41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 161L, 161L
), sp_score = c(0, 3.4, 5, 4.2, 2.1, 1.5), Selection = c("Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Weak")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

A representative graph could be the one attached. As an illustration, each season would match a specific locus "Locus_ID" and the length of the whole x-axis would be represented by the values of "Start"

[image: img]

This is my attempt to accomplish the task

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(Start, sp_score, color = Selection)) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "right", panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10)) + 
  scale_color_igv() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(5000))
```

If it is possible to accomplish the task I wish, I will be grateful for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to map `Start` on `x`, choose the breaks according to the unique values of `Start` and use the `Locus_ID` for the labels:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Dataframe of unique breaks and labels
breaks <- data %>% 
  distinct(Start, Locus_ID)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(Start, sp_score, color = Selection)) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks$Start, labels = breaks$Locus_ID, expand = c(.3, .3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your start is meant to be categorical, if you want an x axis that is continuous ,basically it reflects if the LocusID are close together or far apart, you can basically plot your points with `Start` as x, do away with the x ticks then replace them with an annotation:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x = Start,y=sp_score)) + geom_point() +
stat_summary(aes(label=Locus_ID,x = Start,y=0),geom="text",fun=mean,vjust=2.5) + 
coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,200),clip="off") + 
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update,** after clarification see comments:

thanks for the clarification:
Here is another approach without `facet`

```
df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(Locus_ID_1 = parse_number(Locus_ID)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(Locus_ID_1, Start),
        names_to = "name",
        values_to = "values"
    )

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Locus_ID, y=sp_score, color=Selection)) +
    geom_point(size=2) +
    xlab("Start") +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

**First answer**
Here is a suggestion. I am not sure!

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(Locus_ID_1 = parse_number(Locus_ID)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(Locus_ID_1, Start),
        names_to = "name",
        values_to = "values"
    )

ggplot(df1, aes(x = values, y=sp_score, color=Selection)) +
    geom_point(size=2) +
    facet_wrap(~Locus_ID,  strip.position = "bottom") +
    xlab("Start") +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: `Facet-warp` is not suitable, because as you see, the values of `Start` aren't continuous but are broken every `locus`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, please see my update!

Comment: Great!, do you know how could I include this code `lemon::coord_flex_cart(bottom=brackets_horisontal(), left=capped_vertical('both'))` from `lemon` package. Please check the link [link] (https://github.com/stefanedwards/lemon)

Comment: `library(lemon)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Locus_ID, y=sp_score, color=Selection)) +
    geom_point(size=2) +
    xlab("Start") +
    coord_flex_cart(bottom=brackets_horisontal(), left=capped_vertical('both'))`

Comment: I am not sure if this is your desired output. But it works.

Comment: Well, though the graph fulfils the purpose, I noticed that the order of the locus is wrong. It should be from lowest to greatest as a factor. `df1$Locus_ID <- factor(df1$Locus_ID, levels = unique(order))` Anything similar?